# Twilio python flask try to get status call back event but it returns "none"

Tags: python, flask, twilio, status

I am new to twilio python and flask. I tried to follow the twilio example for tracking sms status, but as I mentionned I get `none` as the return for this statement `status=request.values.get('callstatus', None)`.

I want to track the call progress status and see its different status. I follow all the documentation but I am blocked. Thanks for your help.

```
   from flask import Flask,request
   from twilio.rest import Client
   from twilio.twiml.voice_response import Dial, VoiceResponse
   from pprint import pprint
   import logging
   logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
   app = Flask(__name__)

   twilioClient = Client('*******************', '*****************************')
   @app.route("/voice")
   def voice():

   call=twilioClient.calls.create(
                    method='GET',
                    status_callback='http://*****.ngrok.io/response',
                    status_callback_event='initiated ringing answered completed',
                    status_callback_method='POST',
                    from_='+**********',
                    to='+*********',
                    url='http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml''

                    )

        return call.sid


   @app.route('/response', methods=['POST'])
   def outbound():
      status=request.values.get('callstatus', None)
      logging.info('Status: {}'.format(status))
      return ('', 204)



    if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=true)
```

Comment: did you setup the ngrok proxy for your local server?

Comment: yes i set up the ngrok server.

Comment: and i am using it to make the call and its working fine. http://*****.ngrok.io/voice

Comment: What if you add `'GET'` to the list of `methods`?

Comment: I add the get and i add the call sid but this what i get in  terminal.
INFO:********:127.0.0.1 - - [31/Oct/2019 14:03:56] "GET /response HTTP/1.1" 204 -

INFO:root: SID None Status: None



Thanks.

Comment: and in ngrok terminal i get Get /response  204 NO CONTENT. to run ngrok i use the command ngrok http 5000 could it be a port problem ?

Comment: i did a test from postman on the address http://********.ngrok.io/response and i get a good response :
INFO:*****:127.0.0.1 - - [31/Oct/2019 14:22:18] "POST /response HTTP/1.1" 204 -
INFO:root: SID 123456 Status: ringingTest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that this is a relatively old post and that you might have figured out the solution as of now, but still I am posting my answer so that it will benefit other users who may face the same issue in future.

There are 2 issues that I can see in the code posted above:

1. Inside the function voice()

When you are making a request to the twilio server by using the API twilioClient.calls.create(), you are feeding the status_callback_event parameter with a single string.

Instead of passing a single string, you have to pass a list of strings like:
['initiated', 'answered', 'ringing', 'completed']

2. Inside the function outbound()

The parameter sent by twilio to the call back url is CallStatus and not callstatus. They are case sensitive.

status=request.values.get('CallStatus', None)

You can refer [this link](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource#parameters-sent-to-your-statuscallback-url) to check out all the call resources